# JFrame not updating in real time

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

My project contain two parts: a logical modules and a gui interface.
Both send their references to other.

I have an Key Listener when user sent a message. In this listener I call same gui changes before logic and same changes after logic.
The problem is both changes will be display at the same time, at the end of execution.

How to force the GUI update in real time?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    // Init DecisionEngine and GUIApplication
    private static final Logic _logic = new Logic();
    private static final GUI _gui = new GUI();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set DecisionEngine reference in GUIApplication and viceversa
        _gui.setLogicReference(_logic);
        _logic.setGUIRefecence(_gui);

        // User send a message
        _gui.textInput.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
            @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

                    _gui.somethingChaged1();// CHANGE 1 GUI
                    _logic.thinking();// LOGIC PROCESSING (3sec)
                    _gui.somethingChaged2();// CHANGE 2 GUI

                    e.consume();// Stopping adding an Enter after message
                }
            }
            @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
            @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
        });
    }

    private static class Logic {
        GUI gui_ref;

        public Logic() {}
        private void setGUIRefecence(GUI _gui) {gui_ref = _gui;}
        private void thinking() {
            try {Thread.sleep(3000);} catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    }

    private static class GUI {

        Logic logic_ref;
        private JFrame frame;
        public  JTextArea textInput;
        private JLabel isTyping;

        public GUI() {

            frame = new JFrame();
            textInput = new javax.swing.JTextArea(5, 20);
            isTyping = new JLabel("Normal mode");

            frame.setSize(new Dimension(200,300));
            frame.add(textInput, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            frame.add(isTyping, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        private void setLogicReference(Logic _logic) {logic_ref = _logic;}
        private void somethingChaged1() {isTyping.setText("loading...");System.out.println("status changed in 'loading...'");}
        private void somethingChaged2() {isTyping.setText("is done.");System.out.println("status changed in 'is done.'");}
    }

}
```

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Comment: `private static final logic _logic = new Logic();` will not compile. Also, don't use underscores in variable names in Java.

Comment: @user1803551 Why won't that compile?

Comment: What do the `somethingChanged` methods do?

Comment: Why not check with the compiler why it won't compile? It's not the only compilation error you have.

Comment: @Adrian user1803551 is entirely right, because the capitalization of the first line in your code is inconsistent, this will not compile. From what I gather, your program worked; is this your entire code?

Comment: As a general rule, avoid using `KeyListener` and use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.  It almost sounds like you're block the EDT

Comment: It is a much simplified code. I do not know if it compiles. I just wanted to show how the algorithm is realized.

Comment: `try {Thread.sleep(3000);} catch (InterruptedException ex) {}` ..and you're wondering why it freezes?!?  @MadProgrammer was right.  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify the comment I made in [markbernard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34702156/889583), this is how it should be done:

```
    @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            // Change the GUI from the EDT (current thread):
            _gui.somethingChaged1();

            // start a new Thread to do the long processing:
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                _logic.thinking();// LOGIC PROCESSING (3sec)

                // when the processing in this new Thread is complete,
                // update the GUI again via the EDT:
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                  public void run() {
                    _gui.somethingChaged2();
                  }
                });
              }
            }, "Logic Code");
            t.start();

            e.consume();// Stopping adding an Enter after message
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is right here:

```
        @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

                _gui.somethingChaged1();// CHANGE 1 GUI
                _logic.thinking();// LOGIC PROCESSING (3sec)
                _gui.somethingChaged2();// CHANGE 2 GUI

                e.consume();// Stopping adding an Enter after message
            }
        }
```

You are performing long running fuctions in the event dispatch thread. GUIs update in the event dispatch thread so until you exit your listener no GUI changes will be seen. Try this:

```
        @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  _gui.somethingChaged1();// CHANGE 1 GUI
                  public void run() {
                    _logic.thinking();// LOGIC PROCESSING (3sec)
                    //Changed based on comment from daiscog
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                        _gui.somethingChaged2();// CHANGE 2 GUI
                      }
                    });
                  }
                }, "Logic Code");
                t.start();

                e.consume();// Stopping adding an Enter after message
            }
        }
```

It's also a good practice to name your threads so if you have to debug you can easily find the threads you created.

Comment: @AdrianSimionescu, You logic for the problem is correct. That is the GUI can't repaint itself until the task finishes executing. However, the solution is wrong. The InvokeLater() method executes code on the EDT, so you haven't changed a thing. The solution is to execute the long running task on a separate Thread so you don't block the EDT. One way to do this is to use a `SwingWorker`. Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: I moved _gui.somethingChaged1(); before invokeLater and It's working. It is a good practice?

Comment: @camickr Is right. It's been a while since I did Swing. I will change the code to reflect a normal thread.

Comment: @markbernard Updating the GUI (`_gui.somethingChaged1()` and `_gui.somethingChaged2()`) outside of the event dispatch thread is dangerous.  The correct solution is to call `_gui.somethingChaged1()` from the EDT, then start a new Thread which calls `_logic.thinking();` and then passes another Runnable to `invokeLater()` to call `_gui.somethingChaged2()`

Comment: @daiscog Not true. Swing is not thread safe which is not the same thing. You can perform changes to the underlying objects in your Swing application but the changes won't be visible until you call repaint which runs on the Event Dispatch Thread. In this case he doesn;t  want the GUI updated the second time until the logic is complete. He could take the first update outside of the new thread.

Comment: @markbernard Because Swing is not thread safe, all operations on Swing objects should be performed on the EDT.  What if `_gui.somethingChaged2()`, for example, adds/removes components from the GUI?   If the GUI is in the middle of a repaint operation on the EDT, then fiddling with it in another thread is dangerous.

Comment: @daiscog I'll concede that point. I have updated my answer to reflect that.